# Can't connect database (mysql) with php files on external server

Tags: php, mysql, database, server

Can't connect database (mysql) with below php files from external server (godaddy). warning : mysql_connect() []: cant't connect to mysql server on  (10061) in /files/files/db.php  and also from index.php
`

```
<?php 
$conn=mysql_connect("localhost","dbusername","dbpasswd");
$db=mysql_select_db('dbname',$conn);
?>
```

`
and in db_config.php

`

```
<?php
define('DB_USER', "dbusername"); 
define('DB_PASSWORD', "dbpasswd"); 
define('DB_DATABASE', "dbname"); 
define('DB_SERVER', "server address"); // db server
$servername = "url.com";
$username = "dbusername";
$password = "dbpasswd";
$dbname = "dbname";
$conn=  mysql_connect($servername,$username,$password)or die(mysql_error());
   mysql_select_db('dbname',$conn);
?>
```

`

and in db_connect.php

`

```
<?php
class DB_CONNECT {

    // constructor
    function __construct() {
        // connecting to database
        $this->connect();
    }

    // destructor
    function __destruct() {
        // closing db connection
        $this->close();
    }

    /**
     * Function to connect with database
     */
    function connect() {
        // import database connection variables
        require_once __DIR__ . '/db_config.php';

        // Connecting to mysql database
        $con = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) or die(mysql_error());

        // Selecing database
        $db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE) or die(mysql_error()) or die(mysql_error());

        // returing connection cursor
        return $con;
    }

    /**
     * Function to close db connection
     */
    function close() {
        // closing db connection
        mysql_close();
    }

}

?>
```

`

Comment: First: please don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code. Those functions are no longer available in recent PHP versions, use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead. Second: I'm seeing 3 separate database connections here, which one(s) aren't working? Error 10061 usually means the network connection was refused (i.e. there's no mysql server listening on that host).

Comment: if is external you can not use localhost but you need IP address and then there are possibility for security that is forbidden by server

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem of your code... This problem exists because you are trying to connect a live website with your localhost database. I dont know how to work it out with godaddy because I use MS azure... But I can give you a basic idea - If you want to connect a live website with a database, you will have to make a database on godaddy. I know I answered it too late